# Controlling decimal precision after resetting index of unstacked Pandas data frame

Tags: pandas

My data is as follows:

```
test_df = pd.DataFrame({'Manufacturer':['Ford', 'Ford', 'Mercedes', 'BMW', 'Ford', 'Mercedes', 'BMW', 'Ford', 'Mercedes', 'BMW', 'Ford', 'Mercedes', 'BMW', 'Ford', 'Mercedes', 'BMW', 'Ford', 'Mercedes', 'BMW'],
                          'Metric':['Orders', 'Orders', 'Orders', 'Orders', 'Orders', 'Orders', 'Orders', 'Sales', 'Sales', 'Sales', 'Sales', 'Sales', 'Sales', 'Warranty', 'Warranty', 'Warranty', 'Warranty', 'Warranty', 'Warranty'],
                          'Sector':['Germany', 'Germany', 'Germany', 'Germany', 'USA', 'USA', 'USA', 'Germany', 'Germany', 'Germany', 'USA', 'USA', 'USA', 'Germany', 'Germany', 'Germany', 'USA', 'USA', 'USA'],
                          'Value':[45000, 70000, 90000, 65000, 40000, 65000, 63000, 2700, 4400, 3400, 3000, 4700, 5700, 1500, 2000, 2500, 1300, 2000, 2450],
                          'City': ['Frankfurt', 'Bremen', 'Berlin', 'Hamburg', 'New York', 'Chicago', 'Los Angeles', 'Dresden', 'Munich', 'Cologne', 'Miami', 'Atlanta', 'Phoenix', 'Nuremberg', 'Dusseldorf', 'Leipzig', 'Houston', 'San Diego', 'San Francisco']
                   })
```

I reset the index and create a pivot table, as follows:

```
temp_table = test_df.reset_index().pivot_table(values = 'Value', index = ['Manufacturer', 'Metric', 'Sector'], aggfunc='sum')
```

Then, I create two new data frames:

```
s1 = temp_table.set_index(['Manufacturer','Sector']).query("Metric=='Orders'").Value
s2 = temp_table.set_index(['Manufacturer','Sector']).query("Metric=='Sales'").Value
```

Then, I unstack these data frames:

```
s1.div(s2).unstack()
```

Which gives me:

```
Sector             Germany      USA
Manufacturer
---
BMW               19.117647     11.052632
Ford              42.592593     13.333333
Mercedes          20.454545     13.829787
```

Then, I reset the index:

```
df_out = s1.div(s2).reset_index()
```

Which gives me:

```
    Manufacturer    Sector    Value
0   BMW             Germany   19.117647
1   BMW             USA       11.052632
2   Ford            Germany   42.592593
3   Ford            USA       13.333333
4   Mercedes        Germany   20.454545
5   Mercedes        USA       13.829787
```

**I would like to be able to round the Value column to 2 decimal places.**

I tried to use the `round()` function, as follows:

```
df_out['Value'].round(2)
```

But, this doesn't seem to affect the values when I call `df_out` again.

What is the best way to control the decimal precision in this case?

Thanks!

Comment: Assign the result back to the column.

Comment: df_out['Value']=df_out['Value'].round(2)